# Completing to $n$-th power

Tags: polynomials

I'm familiar with completing to square which is quite easy but I haven't seen completing to cube or in general $n$-th power.I would assume this is not possible since then we would have formula for polynomials of any degree.
So why does completing to second power work but not for $n$ in general
By completing the square I mean
$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a})=a((x+\frac{b}{2a})-(\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{c}{a})=a((x+\frac{b}{2a})-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2})=a(x+\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})(x+\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})$$

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what do you mean under operation "completing to square"?

Comment: Approximating a polynomial of degree $n$ with an element of the form $(x-a)^n$ has limit (if $n>2)$ because you can only 'estimate' it up to first two coefficient of the polynomial unless you are very lucky. You can of course write it of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n b_i(x-a)^i$ but for the sake of 'formula' for roots, it's not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is usually called "completing the square." (Not "to".)

Completing the square is useful because, from the problem $ax^2 + bx + c$,
there are obvious choices of coefficients to assign in your first degree polynomial
to "fit" the first two coefficients of the original polynomial.
To make it even easier, we can first factor out $a$ so that we
are solving $x^2 + Bx + C$, with $B = \frac ba$ and $C= \frac Ca$, and then
try to solve
$$x^2 + Bx + C = (px + q)^2 + \mathrm{something}.$$
Clearly the leading term of $(px + q)^2$ will be $p^2x^2$, but we want $x^2$,
so this is easily accomplished by setting $p = 1$. And then the second term
will be $2pqx = 2qx$, so to get $bx$ we just set $q = \frac B2$.
Now we have
$$x^2 + Bx + C = \left(x + \frac B2\right)^2 + \mathrm{something},$$
and we can cancel terms to get
$$x^2 + Bx + C - \left(x + \frac B2\right)^2 = C - \frac{B^2}{4},$$
so $C - \frac{B^2}{4}$ is the original "something" we needed in order to complete the square:
$$x^2 + Bx + C = (px + q)^2 + \left(C - \frac{B^2}{4}\right).$$
Now we do one more algebra trick, rewrite $C - \frac{B^2}{4}$ as
$-\left(\sqrt{\frac{B^2}{4} - C}\right)^2$, and we have
$$x^2 + Bx + C = (px + q)^2 - \left(\sqrt{\frac{B^2}{4} - C}\right)^2.$$
If we recognize that the right-hand side is just something in the form $u^2 - v^2$, 
we can factor it by the formula $u^2 - v^2 = (u + v)(u - v)$.
And now we have the factors we were looking for,
$u+v$ and $u-v$, each of which is just a
first-degree polynomial in $x$ when we write it out.

What if we try this with a cubic equation? We get
$$x^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D = (px + q)^3 + \mathrm{something},$$
in which we can match the first two terms of the left hand side by
setting $p=1$ and $q = \frac B3$, but if you try to continue on from there
you will find out that the "something" is another polynomial, not just a number.
We get to this:
$$x^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D = \left(x + \frac B3\right)^3 -
 (C - B^2)x + \left(D - \frac{B^3}{27}\right).$$
Now if we could make this look like $u^3 - v^3,$ we might get somewhere,
because $u^3 - v^3 = (u - v)(u^2 + uv + v^2),$
But how do we find $v$ so that
$$v^3 = (C - B^2)x - \left(D - \frac{B^3}{27}\right)?$$
We're stuck.

There is another technique we can use to solve the cubic, but it takes more than
just "completing a cube."
There is an even more complicated procedure to solve fourth-degree (quartic) polynomials.
And then the entire idea of "solving" polynomials by such algebraic means
breaks down.  There is no straightforward algorithm for fifth and higher
degrees like there is for the lower degrees of polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle), the first two coefficients are always $\displaystyle{n\choose0}=1$ and $\displaystyle{n\choose1}=n$.

From Newton's [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), we have $(x+a)^n=x^n+n~a~x^{n-1}+\ldots$ , so by expanding

$\bigg(x+\dfrac An\bigg)^n$ and substituting $t=x+\dfrac An$ as the we variable, we are able to **depress** the initial

polynomial $x^n+Ax^{n-1}+Bx^{n-2}+\ldots$